# Show Absolute Path with Gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, zurb-foundation, gulp-sass

I have the following `gulpfile.js`, which is mostly taken from Foundation css:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var $    = require("gulp-load-plugins")();

var sassPaths = [
  "foundation-sites-6.4.1/_vendor/normalize-scss/sass",
  "foundation-sites-6.4.1/scss",
  "bower_components/motion-ui/src"
];

gulp.task("sass", function() {
  return gulp.src("scss/app.scss")
    .pipe($.sass({
      includePaths: sassPaths
    })
      .on("error", $.sass.logError))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({
      browsers: ["last 2 versions", "ie >= 9"]
    }))
    .pipe(
      gulp.dest("../../res/css")
    )
      .on("end", function(){ /* how to log absolute path of created file */ })
    ;
});
```

I want to output to the console the absolute path for the file that was created, e.g.

```
.on("end", function(){ console.log(...) });
```

But I don't know what to log there, or how to get the absolute path.  I tried to use path.normalize() but that didn't work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you var path = require('path');  first?

Comment: I did.  It kept one set of the `..` which was disappointing.

Answer (score 0):

I see the issue.  I was using

```
path.normalize(__dirname + "../../res")
```

But `__dirname` does not include the trailing slash, so the result kept the first set of `..`.

Using

```
path.normalize(__dirname + "/" + "../../res")
```

Shows the expected path, but looks like the correct way is to use `path.join()`, like so:

```
path.join(__dirname, "../../res")
```